# sql split and update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in sql that needs to be split and update 2 other column with the string.

```
column a :
1000 aa testing it
1000 bb tested
1000 cc done
1000 dd complete
```

i have a column named post where the numbers with 2 letters must come in
and i have a column named status where the rest must come

This must be the end results:

```
column post:
1000 aa
1000 bb
1000 cc
1000 dd
```

column status must be

```
testing it
tested
done
complete
```

Comment: microsoft sql server managemnet studio

Comment: Does all the values in column a follows same pattern ? i.e. 1000 aa, 1000 bb etc

Comment: Try the generic solution below. I have separated string based on second space. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update table_name
set post SUBSTRING(a, 1, 7)

update table_name
set status SUBSTRING(a, 9, 100)
```

(that 100 is just to be sure that you take all)

Comment: Thank you , This was the most easy way to do it ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is a logic to split string at second space.

```
declare @name varchar(100)
set @name = '1000 aa testing it'

SELECT @name as original_string, 
substring(@name, 1,charindex(' ', @name, CHARINDEX(' ',@name) + 1)) as post  ,
substring(@name, charindex(' ', @name, CHARINDEX(' ',@name) + 1),len(@name)-charindex(' ', @name, CHARINDEX(' ',@name) + 1)+1) as status
```

output:

```
original_string      post     status
-------------------  -------- ------------
1000 aa testing it   1000 aa   testing it
```

**[sql demo](http://rextester.com/TAOHSQ33316)**

Answer (score 2):

Use Window `Substring` Function :

```
 SELECT [column a],
       SUBSTRING([column a], 1, 7) [column post],
       SUBSTRING([column a], 9, LEN([column a])) [column status]
FROM <table_name>;
```

**Result :**

```
column a            column post column status
1000 aa testing it  1000 aa     testing it
1000 bb tested      1000 bb     tested   
1000 cc done        1000 cc     done     
1000 dd complete    1000 dd     complete
```

[Click here](http://rextester.com/IYAC97703) for demo

Comment: What if he has data like `100000 dd complete` ??

Comment: Every row in question is following same pattern. Hence, I followed the pattern in my query as well.

Comment: No. You might be right here, but always try to clarify it with OP(like you asked) or provide generic solution which will take care of all scenario :)

Answer (score 1):

This should help, logic to find the occurrence of 1st and 2nd space and using it split the string. [Demo](http://rextester.com/GDMH82910)

```
create table t(str varchar(100));

insert into t(str) values('1000 aa testing it');
insert into t(str) values('1000 bb tested');
insert into t(str) values('1000 cc done');
insert into t(str) values('1000 dd complete')
insert into t(str) values('10000 dd complete'); --Test Case found in comment


select substring(str, 1, P2.Pos - 1) as [column post]
       ,substring(str, P2.Pos +1, len(str)) as [column status]
from   t
cross apply (select (charindex(' ', str))) as P1(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex(' ', str, P1.Pos+1))) as P2(Pos);
```